# Как переопределить встроенный логгер ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно переопределить встроенный логгер? Знаю, что в Serilog есть такая возможность, но нужно без дополнительных библиотек

Comment: ASP.NET или ASP.NET Core?

Comment: на ASP.NET Core